# How do I run a program on someone else's terminal in a fair manner?

Tags: unix

I wish to run a very heavy python script which gobbles up a lot of CPU on someone else's terminal I have access to. This other user logs infrequently on his terminal. I want the program to not take too much CPU resources when the user is logged in. If not then the script should run freely. Is there a UNIX command to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be [nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29) :-)